# How to make kbhit() work in the Spyder environment

Tags: python, keyboard, spyder

Has anyone come across a way to emulate `kbhit()` in the Spyder environment on Windows? Somehow the development environment gets between the Python program and the keyboard, so any simple way of doing it (i.e. `msvcrt.kbhit()`) does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that msvcrt does not work in Spyder is that the iPython console is embedded in a Qt widget (source code [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/9c84cd89625d9ad07f54810588ae6464fa4efef1/spyder/plugins/ipythonconsole/plugin.py)) which handles keyboard input very differently than the CMD [console](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/msvcrt.html#console-i-o).

Mehdi's answer above is the most practical way to get around it. However, it is also possible to connect Spyder to an external IPython console that runs inside a CMD terminal:

1. Open a CMD window
2. Start IPython by running `ipython kernel`. It should print something like

```
cmd> ipython kernel
NOTE: When using the `ipython kernel` entry point, Ctrl-C will not work.

To exit, you will have to explicitly quit this process, by either sending
"quit" from a client, or using Ctrl-\ in UNIX-like environments.

To read more about this, see https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2049


To connect another client to this kernel, use:
    --existing kernel-3436.json
```

3. Open Spyder and connect to the IPython kernel using "Consoles > Connect to an existing kernel". This will open a dialog asking for a connection file.
4. Click the "Browse" button on the far right and select "kernel-3436.json" (the same name that IPython printed when it was started it).
5. If code such as

```
import msvcrt
print('Press a key!')
key = msvcrt.getch()
print('You pressed:', key)
```

is run from Spyder, the output will appear in Spyder's IPython terminal. But to provide input, you have to set focus to the CMD window.

It is even possible to run a debugger, but support for doing so with an external kernel seems very limited. There is no GUI integration. Instead PDB commands must be entered directly into the Spyder IPython terminal. According to [this issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/1256) from 2013, that is unlikely to change.

Answer (score 2):

Set this configuration in Spyder:

Run > Run Configuration Per File > Execute In An External System Terminal

In my experience "msvcrt.kbhit" only works in CMD.

Comment: A quick reminder that normal writing using sentence case, not title case. In typographical terms, title case is not even thought as appropriate for titles these days. Please be willing to change your own personal style preferences based on the prevailing standards of writing for each community you post in.